# How to clear/delete data after a given row index in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I would like to delete all data after row [x]. For example if the x = 355, I want all data to be deleted after 355th row.

I am able to delete all content in a simple sheet in google spreadsheet with:

```
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('foo');
sheet.clearContents();
```

I've tried to do it with getRange method:

```
var range = SpreadsheetApp
               .getActive()
               .getSheetByName("foo")
               .getRange("A20:E71");
range.clearContent();
```

but this is simply deleting inside data from A20:E71. What I want is to delete all data after A20th row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Try:

```
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
                              .getSheetByName(`foo`)
  
  sheet.getRange(21, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-20, sheet.getLastColumn())
       .clearContent()
```

The range is defined as all rows beyond the equivalent of A20.

### Function:

```
function myFunction(allRowsAfter) {

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
                              .getSheetByName(`foo`)
  
  sheet.getRange(allRowsAfter+1, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-allRowsAfter, sheet.getLastColumn())
       .clearContent()

}

myFunction(20); // Delete all rows after 20
```

**See:**

- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)

Comment: Thank you. Can i ask you why do i need "-20". Would not be the same if I get sheet.getLastRow()  where the first row assigned as 21 in sheet.getRange() function

Comment: @UtkuCan That is an example of how to accomplish your question. I've added an additional function if you are planning to use this more than once.

Comment: yes, with the defined function i better understand. thank you very much for your valuable help.

Answer (score 1):

#### Clear everything after row

```
function clearAfterRow(r) {//clear everything after row r 
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("foo");
  const sr = r + 1;
  sh.getRange(sr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1, sh.getLastColumn()).clearContent();
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. Yes, it works but I could not understand why we need ""sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1"" since the range stars from "sr". Would not "sh.getLastRow()" is enough ?

Comment: getLastRow returns the number of the last row not the number of rows between sr and last row

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`getLastColumn()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastcolumn) and [`getLastRow()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow) methods.

The number of rows to be deleted depending on a row `x` can be calculated by `lastRowIndex - x + 1`. In terms of columns you can just delete all columns using `1` as a start value for the range and `lastColumnIndex` for the number of columns to remove.

```js
Logger.log("Starting script...")

const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
const lastRow = ss.getLastRow();
const lastCol = ss.getLastColumn();

const x = 20;
if(lastRow - x + 1 > 0) {
  ss.getRange(20, 1, lastRow - x + 1, lastCol).clearContent();
  Logger.log(`Deleting all content in Range (${[x, 1, lastRow - x + 1, lastCol]})`);
}

Logger.log("Done.")
```

However there is one thing you need to account for in case you run this multiple times or `x` is bigger than the last row with content in you Sheet. You need to check whether the range affects at least one row otherwise you will get an error `The number of rows in the range must be at least 1.`, so check for `lastRow - x + 1 > 0` before deletion.